# How do I programatically control a Chrome instance from the command line?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, remote-control

How do I control a running Google Chrome instance from the command line?  I'm hoping there's something like a `-remote` flag that will allow me to send in some javascript or somesuch.  In particular, I would like to reload the topmost document on the foremost window.

I'm especially interested in Linux/MacOS solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this command line tool if you're on a Mac - it uses the Chrome Scripting API, I guess

https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/ . It might be you can use the Debugging Protocol to do the job.
There is also an [Ruby Client](https://github.com/kzys/chromerepl).
There is also [chromix](https://github.com/smblott-github/chromix).